# Greedy algorithm for rod cutting

Tags: algorithm

This is problem from civil engineering someone looks for a good solution for it

Assume you have a dict of bars you need to cut where the keys are the name of the bar and the values are list of quantity and length required of this kind of bar and the standard length of the bar is 12 m

How to make the most economical solution with the minimum wastage

dict{b1:(3,5),b2:(3,4),b3:(5,2.5)}

notice

1- some times it's more economical to cut 3 pieces of 4 meters which makes a whole bar and this is considered as optimal solution

2-the target is not to make 0 loss but trying to decrease it as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

So, if I read your question correctly, you have an infinite supply of 12m rods, and you are given a request for various quantities of bars, of varying sizes, and you want to figure out how to cut those bars from the supply bars while minimizing the amount of 'wastage' (where wastage is the total length of all the leftover pieces of 12m rods that you had to cut, but were not asked for.)

I don't have a complete solution, but it seems to me the first step would be to make all the bars that are > 6m in length, since each of those bars will *necessarily* require pulling a new 12m rod from your supply. Then your problem space is reduced: you have a finite inventory of bars < 6m long that you don't want to waste if you can avoid it, and an infinite supply of 12m bars, and you need to make all the remaining requested bars that are <= 6m long.

Hope this helps get you started...

Comment: thanks for ur attention 
i solved the problem using brute force algorithm , i generate all the posible combinations then i eliminate the unlogic ones then i choose the answer with min loss 
but now the problem is the first time i tried the program it was very little sample and when i increase it  it gives me MemoryError

Comment: Yeah, usually these algorithms are used when you can't afford to compute all the possibilities via brute force, so you need a heuristic that gets you close to the optimal solution. -- however, if your problem space is small enough that you have time to calculate all the possibilities, all you need to do is calculate the possibilities and measure the waste one at a time, so you only need to 'remember' the best possibility you have come across so far. In other words, don't wait until you have all the possibilities in memory to choose -- just like looping through an array to find the min or max.